# how to view the actual generated keypair generated in webcrypto API

Tags: web

I have generated the key-pair using

```
window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
    name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
    modulusLength: 2048, //can be 1024, 2048, or 4096
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
    hash: { name: "SHA-256" } //can be "SHA-1", "SHA-256", "SHA-384", or "SHA-512"
},
true,
["sign", "verify"]
).then(function(keyPair) {
   console.log("Exporting from keyPair", keyPair);
   console.log("type pf key",typeof(keyPair.publicKey))
})
.catch(function(err) {
   console.error(err);
});
```

But the log displays the public-key and privateKey as objects without the actual representation of the generated key in  the string. Is there any way to find out the actual generated string value of keys.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the key in the clear you will need to export the key:

```
window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
    "jwk", //can be "jwk" (public or private), "spki" (public only), or "pkcs8" (private only)
    publicKey //can be a publicKey or privateKey, as long as extractable was true
)
.then(function(keydata){
    //returns the exported key data
    console.log(keydata);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

That said for security reasons you really only want to use non-exportable keys and not handle the key yourself.